# Get product current selected variation SKU value into pixel datalayer when added to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding a tracking pixel to my website for add to cart event. When I use variation products I need to get product variation sku instead of the main product sku. I have tried so many options to achieve this but I did not get it at all. I always got the non dynamic value and I got the main product SKU without variation atribute.

Is there any option how can I track the add to cart sku from the product page and receive the selected variation SKU into my datalayer?

Code: Search for  //HERE I NEED TO GET CURRENT SELECTED VARIATION SKU to see where I'm trying to get the variation SKU.

Full code is bellow

```
 function pixel_tracker() {
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) return;
    if( is_product() ){
?>

    <!-- Glami piXel -->
        <script>
        (function(f, a, s, h, i, o, n) {f['GlamiTrackerObject'] = i;
        f[i]=f[i]||function(){(f[i].q=f[i].q||[]).push(arguments)};o=a.createElement(s),
        n=a.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];o.async=1;o.src=h;n.parentNode.insertBefore(o,n)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.glami.sk/js/compiled/pt.js', 'glami');

        glami('create', 'AADAD885F5F5FF4D', 'sk');
        glami('track', 'PageView');
        
<?php 
        /*Product view */
        
        /*prida iba do produktov*/
        if( is_product() ){
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        
    
?>  
        /*View content type product*/
        
        glami('track', 'ViewContent', {
        content_type: 'product',
        item_ids: ['<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>'],
        product_names: ['<?php echo $product->get_name(); ?>'] 
        });
        
        /*Add to cart*/ 

        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
                glami('track', 'AddToCart', {
                    item_ids: ['<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>'], //HERE I NEED TO GET CURRENT SELECTED VARIATION SKU
                    product_names: ['<?php echo $product->get_name(); ?>'],
                    value: <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    currency: 'EUR'
                    });
                });
            });

<?php
        }
        

?>

        </script>
    <!-- End Glami piXel -->
    
<?php
}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'pixel_tracker');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can we identify which the current selected variation sku is? Is there a select tag on your page or something of the like?

Comment: Is something like `document.getElementById("select2-pa_velkost-container").innerText` helpful?

Comment: The major thing about this is that Im not that experience in js so if you could demonstrate I would appreciate it.

Comment: I would be happy to do so, but first we need to identify whether this is a good idea. If you could: 1. Right-click anywhere on your page 2. Click on Inspect 3. Click on the Console tab 4. Paste `document.getElementById("select2-pa_velkost-container").innerText` 5. Hit enter 6. Check the result; then the question is: is this value of 42 correct on your page and is this code correct for every test case? If so, I can provide you a solution. If not, then we need to clarify the expectation.

Comment: What do I need is to here  item_ids: ['<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>'] to get this  item_ids: ['<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>/ currently selected variation value'] or item_ids: ['et currently selected product variation sku']  - it has to be all dynamic and update on each select update before product is added to cart.

Comment: Lubo, I think I understand what you intend to do. I have tested my proposed approach and it seems to work. Posting an answer. If I misunderstood the problem, then we can discuss it at the (not yet written) answer.

Comment: Ok I wait for the answer to try it. Thank you Lajos.

Comment: Ochotne! (you are welcome!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to change this line

```
item_ids: ['<?php echo $product->get_name(); ?>'],
```

to this:

```
item_ids: ['<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>_' + document.getElementById("select2-pa_velkost-container").innerText],
```

Explanation: The chosen value is always the `innerText` of the element with the above-mentioned id. I have tested the code just after loading the page, it yielded "42" and then changed the value and ran the test code, it yielded 46. According to my understanding this is what you need.

DISCLAIMER: Since you are using jQuery, you can do something like

```
item_ids: ['<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>_' + document.getElementById("select2-pa_velkost-container").innerText],
```

as well.

Comment: I need to replace not product names but item_ids. But I need to keep echo inside for the sku so we will add something like sku_your select code. How could I do it with the echo for the sku also?

Comment: '<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>_YOUR CODE HERE' something like this

Comment: @LuboMasura I have edited my answer to address your first comment.

Comment: How about the second comment to get 2 values inside one static from the SKU and second from the select with jquery?

Comment: @LuboMasura I am writing an answer for that as we speak

Comment: Okay :) thank you

Comment: @LuboMasura as about the second comment, in Javascript `'foo' + 'bar'` results in `foobar`, the code between `'<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>'` will result in a string. So, the solution is: `'<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>' + document.getElementById("select2-pa_velkost-container").innerText`

Comment: @LuboMasura edited my answer to reflect the solution to the second problem as well. If this does not work yet, please let me know, this is untested code.

Comment: @LuboMasura the static sku form can stay as it was, I believe. It seems that you only need to change code inside the `glami` code.

Comment: is there any way how may I test it live on the page when I switch the variations so I could see the output of the field?