# Get current product category all products parent sku's and display them in array - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get all product sku's in a current category. I have this code so far which is getting me only the IDs. I have also tried to use `meta_query` but I get some errors. I have did some research over the portal and other sites but I did not get it at all. What do I need to do is to display all curent Woocommerce product category products parent sku's in all_ids array.

Code so far

```
$all_ids = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'fields' => 'ids',
      'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'tenisky',
            'operator' => 'IN',
         )
        ),
        ) );
```

Output which gets me the data into my HTML data layers.

```
<?php echo "'" . implode ( "', '", $all_ids ) . "'"; ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to solve this using `get_post_meta`:

```
$all_ids = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'fields' => 'ids',
      'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'tenisky',
            'operator' => 'IN',
         )
        ),
        ) );

$idsku = []; 

for ($index = 0; $index < count($all_ids); $index++) {
    $idsku[$index] = get_post_meta($all_ids[$index], '_sku', true);
}
```

Comment: So what will be the output for php echo after this code is implemented?
<?php echo "'" . implode ( "', '", $id_sku) . "'"; ?> ?

Comment: @LuboMasura almost correct. Remember that I named the array `$idsku`. If you want an underscore, then you need to rename it and change any instance from `$idsku` to `$id_sku`.

Comment: You are right. My bad. It works as charm! Thank you. One more question could you please also check on my another question if you have a free time. If you are a javascript exper you may help me to get it work. I would appraciate it. Thank you for your help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69867886/get-product-current-selected-variation-sku-value-into-pixel-datalayer-when-added

Comment: @LuboMasura you are welcome! Looking at the other one.

Comment: You are more than welcome. Polak, Węgier, dwa bratanki, i do szabli, i do szklanki.

Comment: Hahah Im slovak but I understand :D

Comment: Sorry, I misidentified it. Nevertheless, happy to help.